# What is the correct way of using ntlm authentication with RESTClient?

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

The follow code works fine but `AuthPNames` and `AuthPolicy` are marked as depreciated and I cannot find anything on what to replace it with.

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

def restClient = new RESTClient(config.server)

restClient.client.credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
   AuthScope.ANY, 
   new NTCredentials(
      config.authUsername, 
      config.authPassword, 
      config.authWorkstation, 
      config.authDomain)
)
restClient.client.params.setParameter(
   AuthPNames.TARGET_AUTH_PREF, 
   [AuthPolicy.NTLM]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in the docs:

- For [AuthPNames](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/auth/params/AuthPNames.html), [RequestConfig](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html) and [AuthSchemeProvider](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/auth/AuthSchemeProvider.html) should be used
- For [AuthPolicy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/params/AuthPolicy.html), [AuthSchemes](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/AuthSchemes.html) should be used.

Comment: @AndrewSummer, is that what You're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but... I cannot figure out from the documentation how RequestConfig and AuthSchemeProvider should be used.

Comment: @AndrewSumner, I don't know why You unaccepted the answer. You were asking for *what* the classes can be replaced with not *how*. The answer is: it's not possible now. As You can see here http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder%7Chttp-builder%7C0.7.1%7Cjar, in http-builder `4.2.1` version of httpcomponents is used, and the classes I mentioned were introduced in `4.3.6`. You need to substitute old library with newer version (no idea if possible - mind the dependencies) or wait till new version of library will be used in http-builder.

Comment: Great, that was the answer I was after - it can't be done yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code, it worked for me.

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

def restClient = new RESTClient(config.server)

restClient.auth.ntlm config.authUsername, config.authPassword, config.authWorkstation, config.authDomain
```